# How to detect that any blackberry application is screen density supportive or not?

Tags: blackberry, bold

I want to develop one application which I will install on my Bold Device.now is it possible for my application to retrieve information regarding application which are installed on my device that these applications can be installed on other devices like Torch/Storm/Tablet phones of blackberry. is it possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: Just curious... are you using Java or WebWorks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even Java API, with richer than Web-SDK functionality, does not provide such information about installed applications. To inspect all possible actions over installed apps look at `CodeModuleManager` and `ApplicationManager` classes from RIM API SDK.